# How to find which graphic card is there on my laptop?

Tags: graphics

I bought new laptop, in specs they had given *nvidia GT 740m*.

How can I confirm whether this is correct or not? How can I see which graphic card is installed?

Answer (score 1):

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

The above command does the job.

Comment: will it show nvidia even when nvidia drivers not installed??

Comment: yes it shows the graphics card attached even if you not installed it's corresponding drivers.

Comment: when i type this command lspci -nn |egrep "VGA|Display"                                            it's showing this  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0a16] (rev 09)

Comment: but when i type this  sudo lshw -C video                            it's showing this  description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:60 memory:b5000000-b53fffff

Comment: *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0

Comment: so which one is correct first one or second one(that in last two comments , can't show in one comment due to restriced characters)

Comment: both are correct.

Comment: why is it showing display UNCLAIMED for Nvidia??

Answer (score 0):

In the software manager you can download the Nvidia drivers and control panel. From the control panel it will display information such as the type of card and it's current performance.